# Location service randomly not working

Tags: ios, swift, gps, location, core-location

I have a strange issue with the apple location service. 
First of all the code that I'm using to get user location:

```
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UISplitViewControllerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //Core location
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //Core Location
        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        //Clore Location
        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        return true
    }
```

And my info.plist file:

[image]

Randomly, when I launch the simulator, my app don't get the location. Normally I change the simulator device, from iphone 6s to iphone 6 and it fix the issue. But today I've changed from a city to another and I'm having this issue in my device all the time. I cannot get the location. Anybody have an idea what can it be? Is this a bug from apple? Is there a solution?

Thanks!

EDIT: added didUpdateLocations but the whole problem is this method is never being called

```
//Core Location Delegate Methods
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    //Set coordinates to global var
    let coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    locValue = coordinates

    setCoordinatesDetails(coordinates)
    if(self.hasBeenLaunched == false){
        self.hasBeenLaunched = true
        loadCitySlugArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: try on device, make sure your device not connected with system.

Comment: sorry what is "connected with system" ? by the way, I'm trying on device and never works now

Comment: Can you show us your `didUpdateLocation` method ?

Comment: no problem, but the problem is precisely this method is never called